# Restructuredtext tables NOT rendered with zebra stripes on github

Tags: github, restructuredtext

Is there a way to configure restructuredtext tables to not render with zebra stripes?

Here is an example of a cell in my table:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| How are we going to get the user? | The user will be entered in a form  |
|                                   |                                     |
|                                   | ``src/app/home/home.tpl.html``      |
|                                   |                                     |
|                                   | .. code:: html                      |
|                                   |                                     |
|                                   |     <form>                          |
|                                   |       <label>Name:</label>          |
|                                   |       <input ng-model="username" /> |
|                                   |     </form>                         |
|                                   |     <hr/>                           |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

When this is rendered both the zebra stripes and the code are rendered as light grey confusing the reader. You can see the problem [here](https://github.com/zhon/wisdom-bot-kata-angular).

If this is not possible, are there other suggestions for getting tables without zebra stripes on github.